# Am I in the right place?

Tags: discussion

I have a small python program (1000 lines) that I'm pretty sure could use some fundamental internal core restructuring or at least re-orienting. Is Code Review the right place to ask *"what's the biggest / most important thing to change in X?"* I could break out some of the pieces I have the most confusion about and post for review, but perhaps they're not actually the most important parts to fix first... What do you suggest?

code: http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/browser/trunk/apt
intro: http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/pkg-apt

Answer (score 9):

This definitely the right place, but if you post the whole 1000 lines, there probably won't be many people who will bother reading it. So you probably have a better chance if you extract the important bits and post those - accompanied by a link to the whole code for context.